# What are responsibilities of being a Software Tester?

Tags: qa-role, tester

Is creating wireframes a part of Software Testing job?
I am a newbie in Software Testing.
What would be the possible responsibilities of being a Software Tester?

Comment: For inspiration you can look _here_: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/what-are-the-main-role-and-responsibilities-of-a-tester

Comment: And _here_: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8073/universal-skills-in-a-qa-role/

Comment: But maybe mostly: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-are-key-properties-of-a-great-qa-team-member/

Comment: Updated title to reflect details

Answer (score 4):

> What would be the possible responsibilities of being a Software Tester?

That is covered [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/what-are-the-main-role-and-responsibilities-of-a-tester).

> I need to know if creating wire frames a part of Software Testing job?

That depends on what your employer needs and what you are capable of.  In a tiny company, you might need to write the test cases, draw the wire frames, manage the bug tracking system, fix the copy machine, and maintain the wireless router.  In a big company with lots of specialized positions, you might only do nothing but follow a test script that someone else wrote for you.